# MYSQL Query for top 10 users per location

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I Need to get the top 10 users per CC, based on total prints they have made.

Hierarchy looks like this

1. Business Unit
2. Cost Centre
3. User

It is a one to many relation.

Tables look like this:

```
Business Unit
'id', name, bu_no

Cost Center
'id', bu_id, name

User
'id', username, fullname, email, total_prints
```

This is currently in Excel, but I will get the data into MySQL.

I need to find the MySQL query to show top 10 users (most prints) per Cost Centre.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to find good answers here on StackOverflow by searching for the tags `[mysql]` and `[greatest-n-per-group]`.

Comment: http://frishit.com/2010/07/mysql-selecting-top-n-per-group/

Comment: How is your user connected to the other tables? What tells you they have x prints and CC 1 and y prints at CC 2? Looks to me like your user table is an island.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661373/getting-the-avg-of-the-top-10-students-from-each-school/4661473#4661473 for a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting by Descending would put the most prints at the top and the LIMIT 10 would select only the top ten records.

Here is a code sample to show what I'm talking about.

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.Id = Cost_Center.Id ORDER By total_prints DESC LIMIT 10;
```