# Getting the avg of the top 10 students from each school

Tags: mysql, limit, temp-tables

We have a school district with 38 elementary schools.  The kids took a test.  The averages for the schools are widely dispersed, but I want to compare the averages of JUST THE TOP 10 students from each school.

Requirement: use temporary tables only.

I have done this in a very work-intensive, error-prone sort of way as follows.
(sch_code = e.g., 9043; 
 -- schabbrev = e.g., "Carter"; 
 -- totpct_stu = e.g., 61.3)

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS avg_top10 ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE avg_top10
   ( sch_code   VARCHAR(4),
     schabbrev  VARCHAR(75),
     totpct_stu DECIMAL(5,1)
   );

INSERT 
  INTO avg_top10
SELECT sch_code
     , schabbrev
     , totpct_stu
  FROM test_table
 WHERE sch_code IN ('5489')
 ORDER
    BY totpct_stu DESC
 LIMIT 10;

-- I do that last query for EVERY school, so the total 
-- length of the code is well in excess of 300 lines.  
-- Then, finally...

SELECT schabbrev, ROUND( AVG( totpct_stu ), 1 ) AS top10
  FROM avg_top10
 GROUP
    BY schabbrev
 ORDER
    BY top10 ;

-- OUTPUT:
-----------------------------------
schabbrev   avg_top10
----------  ---------
Goulding         75.4
Garth            77.7
Sperhead         81.4
Oak_P            83.7
Spring           84.9
-- etc...
```

Question: So this works, but isn't there a lot better way to do it?

Thanks!

PS -- Looks like homework, but this is, well...real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [this technique](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/).

```
select sch_code,
       schabbrev,
       ROUND( AVG( totpct_stu ), 1 ) AS top10
from   (select sch_code,
               schabbrev,
               totpct_stu,
               @num := if(@group = sch_code, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
               @group := sch_code as dummy
        from   test_table
        order by sch_code, totpct_stu desc) as x
where  row_number <= 10
GROUP BY sch_code,
       schabbrev
```

Comment: Wow!  My eyes bugged out when I saw how compact the code is.  From hundreds of lines down to 13.  Yes, it works like butter.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: In MySQL 5.5.40 this doesn't quite work (at least when joining other tables to test_table) because the order by happens after the row numbers get assigned. I had to take everything being selected from in the derived table and wrap it within another derived table containing the order by clause in order to get it to work. Great solution overall, though!