# How to SELECT an AVG of the TOP n grouped values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

The Database:

```
player  |  team  |  points  
player1 | team1  |  100
player2 | team1  |  90
player3 | team2  |  100
player4 | team2  |  95
player5 | team2  |  90
```

I am trying to get the top 2 players from each team's points and average them towards the teams ranking, while grouping the teams in a query:

```
team2 97.5 (not 95)
team1 95


       `$mysqli->query("SELECT charGuild, gr FROM (
        SELECT charGuild, AVG(charRating) as gr 
        FROM ins_rated 
        GROUP BY charGuild 
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
        ORDER BY gr DESC
        LIMIT 15
        )
       ORDER BY gr DESC
       LIMIT 40");`
```

Is not working as expected.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT charGuild, AVG(charRating) AS gr 
                                        FROM ins_rated 
                                        GROUP BY charGuild 
                                        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
                                        ORDER BY gr DESC
                                        LIMIT 40");
```

Is listing the top teams, whom have at least 10 people in the db. Now adding in a way to get the top 15 players ONLY to average out the teams scores is where I am lost.

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661373/getting-the-avg-of-the-top-10-students-from-each-school/4661473#4661473

Comment: @Martin It looks like it will get the job done, but it's outputting the default values I already can achieve. ie. the filter in the subselect is doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT charGuild, AVG(charRating) as gr FROM ins_rated GROUP BY charGuild order by gr desc limit 2
```

Comment: This doesn't quite get it where I want to go with it. The charGuild group needs a limiter of the top 15 in the group, but I want a big list of all the charGuild's or 'teams'.

Answer (score 0):

> Error Code : 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

I think you might need to use some coding.

Best I could do is:

```
SELECT charGuild, charRating
FROM ins_rated a
WHERE charRating = (SELECT MAX(charRating) FROM ins_rated b WHERE b.charGuild = a.charGuild)
OR charRating = (SELECT MAX(charRating) FROM ins_rated b WHERE b.charGuild = a.charGuild
    AND charRating < (SELECT MAX(charRating) FROM ins_rated c WHERE c.charGuild = a.charGuild));
```

outputs:

```
charGuild     charRating   
team 1        100          
team 1        90           
team 2        100          
team 2        95
```

**EDIT: Scratch that. It's getting the 2 highest *unique* scores. If 2 players on the team got 100, it would not choose (100,100) as the highest scores, but (100,95).**

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo!

```
SELECT charGuild, AVG(charRating) average
FROM (SELECT charRating, charGuild FROM ins_rated a ORDER BY charRating DESC LIMIT 4) top4
GROUP BY charGuild
```

Outputs:

```
charGuild           average  
team 1              95.0000  
team 2              97.5000
```

**EDIT: Scratch that. This one assumes the number of teams is known, and that each team has at least 2 people.**

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:
It doesn't have any of the flaws of my other 2 answers...

```
SELECT charGuild, AVG(charRating) average
FROM (
    SELECT
        charRating,
        charGuild,
        @num := IF(@guild = charGuild, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @guild := charGuild
    FROM ins_rated a
        ORDER BY charGuild DESC
) ordered
WHERE row_number <= 2
GROUP BY charGuild;
```

Output:

```
charGuild     average
team 1        95.0000         
team 2        97.5000
```

Comment: This solution seems to work on paper but for some reason is not working correctly on my server. Is there a certain flag I need to turn on? The @num+1 is not working at all. Each @guild has a value of 1 as if they are all unique spellings (which they aren't as they do group...

Comment: http://www.insomniaguild.org/paul/test.php You can see here, the nested query is not performing the +1...

Comment: I'm using MySQL Version 5.1.36. Maybe it's new... Are you able to upgrade?

Comment: I will ask my web host tonight. It's doing this on two different servers though, so I am not sure what the deal is.